# how to get list of files in a directory recursively in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, typescript

I wrote this code and it works fine, that is written in TypeScript. When I use the same code in the test file in Cypress I get error `TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function`

```
import * as fs from 'fs'

let inputPath: String = "C:\\Users\\rkon";


let replacementString = "/";
let newInputPath = inputPath.split('\\').join(replacementString)
console.log('path after replacement: ' + newInputPath);
fs.readdir(newInputPath as string, function (err: any, files: any[]) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    }
    //listing all files using forEach
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        console.log('f: ' + file);

    });
});
```

I verified the above code by first doing

```
>tsc temp.ts
>node temp.js
```

As I said it worked fine but not sure why does the same code does not work in Cypress and gives the error

`TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function`

Here is the **tsconfig.json**

```
{
     "compilerOptions": {

        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "lib": ["es2017"],
        "typeRoots": ["./typings","./node_modules/@types","node_modules/@types/node","node_modules/@types"],
        "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["./node_modules/@types/*"]
        },
        "outDir": "build/"
    }

}
```

Here are the versions

```
>node -v
v12.13.0

>npm -v
6.12.0

>tsc -v
Version 3.7.2

>.\node_modules\.bin\cypress -v
Cypress package version: 3.5.0
Cypress binary version: 3.5.0
>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.805]
```

Comment: Hi show your tsconfig , I think you should add the node type also into the tsconfig and package.json for this to work .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43048371/6793637

Comment: @PDHide I do have `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]`  in package.json

Comment: if I run `>tsc temp.ts --noResolve`  then I get error `temp.ts:14:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'.`

Comment: it might have to do something with Cypress as it runs the tests in browser. I see some options like [brfs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brfs) and [browserify-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs)

Comment: Yes I think you might need to use fs-extra plugin instead

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly both the statements below work well in Windows machine to get the directory (Note that this solution is a workaround due to the fact that Cypress tests run in browser environment.)

```
        cy.exec('pwd').then((result) =>
            cy.log('pwd res:' + JSON.stringify(result))
        );

        cy.exec('cd').then( (result) =>
            cy.log('cd res:' + JSON.stringify(result))
        );
```